# Why is this bash while loop infinite?

Tags: bash, while-loop, infinite

This is my first time making a bash script...

I'm trying to make a bash script that will delete the oldest file in a directory until said directory is under a certain size. I want the while look to stop once the directory is under 10000 bytes. 10000 is just for testing; I will increase it later.

du and cut puts the directory size in bytes into the variable called check
The while look should run while the file size is greater than 10000 bytes.
For each iteration the oldest file in the directory is deleted.

When I run this script, the oldest file is deleted, but it reiterates infinitely even when $check becomes less than 10000. Why does this script keep running infinitely?

```
check = $(du -sb /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor | cut -f1)

while [ $check -gt 10000 ]
check = $(du -sb /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor | cut -f1)
do
cd /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor
ls /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor -1tr | head -1 | xargs rm
done
```

This is the output I get once the script has removed all files from the directory.

```
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

And this runs over and over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your script:

The **first mistake** is the broken `while` clause, it should read

```
while condition; do
    commands
done
```

or

```
while condition
do
    commands
done
```

whereas `condition` might be a test expression that returns zero or non-zero as you *correctly* wrote:

```
[ $check -gt 10000 ]
```

The line

```
check = $(du -sb /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor | cut -f1)
```

before the `do` is mislocated. I bet you wanted to put it after the `do` to get the value again.

The **second mistake** is your `xargs` usage. Since the list of files you want to pass to `xargs` might be empty, you'd add the switch `--no-run-if-empty` to fix the `rm: missing operand` error.

To avoid writing the `check` line twice you could write a while-true loop and check the condition inside and break out of the loop, since bash has no head-controlled while-loop.

```
while [ true ]; do
   check = ...
   if [ $check -le 10000 ]; then
       break
   fi

   ...
done
```

---

Other sugestions

- You don't need to do the `cd` every time in the loop, do it before
- If you'd like to remove files older than a specific amount of time rather than by checking the directory size you may use `find -mtime +N` (find files with modification date older (`+`) than `N` days)
- Sometimes bash's `pushd` and `popd` are very convinient over `cd` because `cd` has changed the directory after script execution you'd need to remember the previous directory to `cd back. With`pushd`you tell bash to do set the current directory where`popd` brings you back to the previous directory. On [directory stack functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Directory-Stack-Builtins-1)

Comment: Environment changes, including changing directory, don't propagate back to the parent shell. So if his script does a "cd" command, when the script exits, your shell will still be where it was when it executed the script.

Comment: Thank you and everyone else for informative answers

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine the `do` has to be *before* the reassignment of `check`. Otherwise it is not actually part of the body of the loop. Also the assignment should probably be done *after* the body executes (and before the next test of the loop condition):

```
check=$(du -sb /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor | cut -f1)

while [ $check -gt 10000 ]
do
cd /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor
ls /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor -1tr | head -1 | xargs rm
check=$(du -sb /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor | cut -f1)
done
```

I've also removed the spaces around the `=` to make your `check=...` lines actually assignment statements.

Comment: almost. Just move the check inside the loop to be updated after the deletion, otherwise it deletes one file too many.

Comment: Note that the first line `check = $(du -sb /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor | cut -f1)` with spaces around the `=` runs a command `check` with operators `=` and the results of the command substitution!

Answer (score 0):

There are two commands in your while-loop clause, `[ $check -gt 10000 ]` and  `check = $(du -sb /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor | cut -f1)` (which is a bad command and not an asssignment because of the spaces around the `=`-sign) . The latter command is the only one that determines if the while loop ever terminates. If its return code is always 0 then the while loop never finishes..

If there are no files then the `rm` command has no operand and hence the error message..

Answer (score 0):

Don't put spaces around the = in assignments

```
check=$(du -sb /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor | cut -f1)

while [ $check -gt 10000 ]
check = $(du -sb /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor | cut -f1)
do
cd /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor
ls /home/chris/Dropbox/VideoMonitor -1tr | head -1 | xargs rm
done
```